# json parse. Extract 2 values from multiple records and merge into one cell, with array formula

Tags: json, regex, google-sheets, array-formulas, re2

I'm trying to use a formula to extract the values from each "hash" in table cells A1:A and concatenate them in cells B1:B separated by commas

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i2qLX-BfZ6ZpWNzpgAVHsNSTG8HjwbhSFVfqtp8bMhc/edit?usp=sharing

**JSON**

**A1**

```
{
"2Qk1xsOqhlxUe5d3fiJVcXgBLaBODegmo":{
"hash":"2Qk1xsOqhlxUe5d3fiJVcXgBLaBODegmo",
"name":"logo2.png",
"description":"",
"type":"image/png",
"path":"/logo2.png",
"size":"13 KB"
},
"1W2HdCGmeMLz1u0kzvxdUhGyEwIUlMD-s":{
"hash":"1W2HdCGmeMLz1u0kzvxdUhGyEwIUlMD-s",
"name":"logo.png",
"description":"",
"type":"image/png",
"path":"/logo.png",
"size":"29 KB"
}
}
```

**A2**

```
{
"5Qk1xsOqhlxUe5d3fiJVcXgBLaBODegmo":{
"hash":"5Qk1xsOqhlxUe5d3fiJVcXgBLaBODegmo",
"name":"logo2.png",
"description":"",
"type":"image/png",
"path":"/logo3.png",
"size":"13 KB"
},
"4W2HdCGmeMLz1u0kzvxdUhGyEwIUlMD-s":{
"hash":"4W2HdCGmeMLz1u0kzvxdUhGyEwIUlMD-s",
"name":"logo.png",
"description":"",
"type":"image/png",
"path":"/logo4.png",
"size":"29 KB"
}
}
```

**Extracted value (Hash)**

**B1**

```
2Qk1xsOqhlxUe5d3fiJVcXgBLaBODegmo,1W2HdCGmeMLz1u0kzvxdUhGyEwIUlMD
```

**B2**

```
5Qk1xsOqhlxUe5d3fiJVcXgBLaBODegmo,4W2HdCGmeMLz1u0kzvxdUhGyEwIUlMD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(
 REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "[""\{\}\n ]|-s", ), "hash:.*"), "hash:", ), 
 "name.*", ))),,9^9))), " |,$", ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `regexextract()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  textjoin( 
    ",", 
    true, 
    iferror( 
      regexextract( 
        query( 
          transpose( split(A2, "," & char(10), true, true) ), 
          "where Col1 contains 'hash' ", 0 
        ), 
        "hash"":""(\w+)"
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Thank you! But unfortunately only one value is retrieved. I tried to use this formula `=REGEXEXTRACT(A3,"""hash"":""(.+?)""")` but it only extracts one value.

Comment: To extract multiple values from one cell, use the formula I gave above. To extract multiple values from the whole column use @player0's formula.